# AngularJS paginated table: limitTo parameters do not update in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am displaying a JSON in a Bootstrap 3 table, in AngularJS.

I am working on paginating the table, with the help of the `limitTo` filter:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module
app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = root + "/users"
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // Users arary
      $scope.users = data.data;

      // Order by function
      $scope.orderByMe = function(criteria) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = criteria;
      }

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 5;
      $scope.startAt = 0;

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
        $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
      };

    });
}]);
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.container {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.search-box {
  margin: 5px;
}
.panel-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.table-container table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.table-container table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.table-container table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-container table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr th:last-child, .table-container table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

/* Media queries */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group search-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search User" data-ng-model="search">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Full name</th>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('email')">Email</th>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('city')">City</th>
                  <th>Street</th>
                  <th>Suite</th>
                  <th>Zipcode</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search|orderBy:myOrderBy| limitTo : perPage : startAt">
                  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                  <td><a href="mailto:{{user.email  | lowercase}}">{{user.email  | lowercase}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center">Page {{pageNum}}</p>
          <p class="text-center">Show users from {{startAt + 1}} to {{startAt + perPage}}</p>
          <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="pager">
              <li><a href="#" ng-click="prevPage()">&larr; Previous</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" ng-click="nextPage()">Next &rarr;</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Upon clicking the *Next* and *Prev* buttons, the `startAt` parameter of the `limitTo` *does* update in the view, as can be seen in the paragraph below the table, but the `data-ng-repeat` does not (re)use it *updated*.

How do I render the table at every update of `startAt`?
What is missing from my script?

Comment: try a newer version of angularjs: `/1.2.23/angular.min.js` --> `/1.6.9/angular.min.js`

Comment: Can you put togheter a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.2.23 doesn't have begin in limitTo, lowest version I found that supports begin is 1.4.0

Here is a working plunk. https://plnkr.co/edit/bcrlKW46zlZ20k6E57M4

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a "modern" version of AngularJS did the job:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module
app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = root + "/users"
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // Users arary
      $scope.users = data.data;

      // Order by function
      $scope.orderByMe = function(criteria) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = criteria;
      }

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 5;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.usersCount= $scope.users.length;
      $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.usersCount/$scope.perPage);

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

    });
}]);
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.container {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.search-box {
  margin: 5px !important;
}
.panel-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.table-container .table-responsive {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.table-container table {
  border-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-container p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-container .pager {
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}
.table-container table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.table-container table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-container table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr th:last-child, .table-container table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

/* Media queries */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group search-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search User" data-ng-model="search">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Full name</th>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('email')">Email</th>
                  <th ng-click="orderByMe('city')">City</th>
                  <th>Street</th>
                  <th>Suite</th>
                  <th>Zipcode</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search|orderBy:myOrderBy| limitTo : perPage : startAt">
                  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                  <td><a href="mailto:{{user.email  | lowercase}}">{{user.email  | lowercase}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center">Show users {{startAt + 1}} to {{startAt + perPage}} of {{usersCount}} users </p>
          <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="pager">
              <li><a href="#" ng-click="prevPage()">&larr; Previous</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" ng-click="nextPage()">Next &rarr;</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better (and nicer) version:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module
app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = root + "/users"
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // Users arary
      $scope.users = data.data;

      // Order by function
      $scope.orderByMe = function(criteria) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = criteria;
      }

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 3;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.itemsCount = $scope.users.length;
      $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
      
      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };
    });
}]);
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.container {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.search-box {
  margin: 5px !important;
}
.panel-heading {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.table-container table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.table-container table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.table-container table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-container table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-container table tr th:last-child, .table-container table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.table-container .pagination-info {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.pager {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

/* Media queries */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
<div class="panel panel-default table-container">
  <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
  <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group search-box">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search User" data-ng-model="search">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Full name</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('email')">Email</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('city')">City</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Suite</th>
                <th>Zipcode</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search|orderBy:myOrderBy| limitTo : perPage : startAt">
                <td>{{$index + startAt + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td><a href="mailto:{{user.email  | lowercase}}">{{user.email  | lowercase}}</a></td>
                <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <p class="pagination-info text-center">Page {{pageNum}} of {{pageMax}}</p>
        <div class="text-center" ng-if="pageMax > 1">
          <ul class="pager">
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="prevPage()">&larr; Previous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="nextPage()">Next &rarr;</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```